# This is why I shouldn't leave my notebook out in my sleep

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

So, last night, I accidentally left my notebook out on my nightstand, because I was doing homework late.

When I woke up, it was open (which it wasn't before!). My hands were covered in ink, and there were some really weird symbols on the page the notebook was open to.

[image]

I wrote them (my hands were inky), so there must be some meaning to my sleep-writing, perhaps something important? Can you find anything in the odd symbols?

P.S. Even in my sleep, I'm not a good drawer, keep that in mind if you find any oddities.

Hints coming maybe, there is at least one already hidden.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Building off [gabbo1092's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/74829/49474),

> 2X 5Y 3R 1W 4V
> 1B 3M 5H 4J 2U
> 4U 7N 6G 3V 1T 5U 2G
> 1I 3H 6B 2Y 5H 7M 4J
> 1E 3V 4T 2C
> 2V 6F 3R 1R 5H 4Y
>  
> These correspond to directions on a keyboard - trace a path from letter to letter in numerical order within each line. For example, the first line traces W X R V Y, creating the letter W.
> This spells out the final answer **WAKE UP**. Sounds like it worked!

Comment: Pretty sure you've got the first letter upside down :)

Comment: ROT13(V guvax gur svefg yrggre vf j fcryyvat jnxr hc) and I think you got it!

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu I think jafe means that Level 51 has the first letter upside down...

Comment: @El-Guest phew, I started second guessing myself lol.

Comment: @jafe: ha, I did indeed! The new answer makes a ton more sense, too :P (edited in the new answer!)

Comment: @Level51: one more correction would be in your second to last line, creating the letter.... (otherwise, +1 from me! Great job!!)

Comment: @El-Guest: good catch (and edited in)! Though of course I'm going to pretend none of this brainfart ever happened :))

Answer (score 12):

## Partial Answer

The markings are:

> letter and number overlayed and mirrored.

My interpretation of them:

> 2X 5Y 3R 1W 4V 
> 1B 3M 5H 4J 2U 
>  4U 7N 6G 3V 1T 5U 2G 
>  1I 3H 6B 2Y 5H 7M 4J 
>  1E 3V 4T 2C 
>  2V 6F 3R 1R 5H 4Y  
>  
>  Each 'word' has numbers that count up to the number of letters in that word(i.e. a 5 letter word has 1,2,3,4,5). If you order each letter based on the corresponding numbers you get:
>  WXRVY 
>  BUMJH 
>  TGVUUGN 
>  IYHJHBM 
>  ECVT 
>  RVRYHF  
>  So far I've tried shifting the letters but no clear answer from that yet. Still looking further.

Comment: Yup, you're on the right track.

Comment: Great start! I think r13(gur barf lbh'er zvffvat ner obgu W'f)

Comment: @El-Guest Thank you! somehow must've forgot that letter

Comment: ROT13(Nyy bs gur yvarf unir ahzoref pbeerfcbaqvat bar gb gur ahzore bs yrggre va gur yvar)... not sure if that's helpful (and I apologize if you already noticed) or what to do with that info

Comment: @Greg I was just looking at that now will update my answer if I find anything

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

Letters:

> 2X 5Y 3R 1W 4V  
>  1B 3M 5H 4J 2U 
>  4C 7N 6G 3V 1T 5U 2G  
>  1I 3H 6B 2Y 5H 7M 4J  
>  1E 3V 4T 2C 
>  2V 6F 3R 1R 5H 4Y

The clue in the puzzle already:

> Mentions finding anything in the odd symbols, which means let's look at only the odd numbered ones:

So that's:

> 5Y 3R 1W
>  1B 3M 5H 
>  7N 3V 1T 5U
>  1I 3H 5H 7M
>  1E 3V
>  3R 1R 5H

I've tried

> Shifting them forwards and backwards the number on the letter, so i'm thinking it's something else? 5H seems to be repeated a few times which might pare down a frequency or something.